# Hibernate creates only some tables

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hibernate hbm2ddl only creates 2 of 6 tables when the SessionFactory is creating.

**Example of table that is created:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITIES")
public class Authorities {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;


  @Column(name = "AUTHORITY", nullable=false)
  private String authority;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", nullable=false)
  private User user;
...getters, setters...
```

**Example of table that isn't created:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXERCISES")
public class Exercise {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;


  @Column(name = "NAME", nullable=false)
      private String name;


  @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
      private String description;
...getters, setters...
```

## Hibernate properties

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

SQL from console:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists AUTHORITIES cascade
Hibernate: drop table if exists USERS cascade
Hibernate: create table AUTHORITIES (id  serial not null, AUTHORITY varchar(255) not null, USERNAME varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table USERS (USERNAME varchar(255) not null, ENABLED boolean not null, PASSWORD varchar(255) not null, primary key (USERNAME))
Hibernate: alter table AUTHORITIES add constraint FKl8gm1dxqhdixkdsm1p7er9c21 foreign key (USERNAME) references USERS
```

Database is remote ElephantSQL.

Comment: what's the other tables?

Comment: Can't tell from what you've posted.  There must be other informative messages somewhere.  Or perhaps there's missing configuration that we're not seeing.

Comment: I've posted one table that is created, and one that isn't. I can paste them all if it's necesery. What configuration should I show you?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, as [duffymo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/37213/duffymo) pointed, the configuration was wrong.

```
  @Bean
```

public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

```
Properties props = new Properties();

// Setting JDBC properties
props.put(DRIVER, env.getProperty("driver"));
props.put(URL, env.getProperty("jdbcUrl"));
props.put(USER, env.getProperty("username"));
props.put(PASS, env.getProperty("password"));

// Setting Hibernate properties
props.put(SHOW_SQL, env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
props.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
props.put(DIALECT, env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));

// Setting C3P0 properties
props.put(C3P0_MIN_SIZE, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size"));
props.put(C3P0_MAX_SIZE, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size"));
props.put(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment"));
props.put(C3P0_TIMEOUT, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout"));
props.put(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS, env.getProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements"));

factoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class, Authorities.class, Exercise.class, ExerciseUnit.class, Routine.class, Training.class);

return factoryBean;
```

I've forget to set new entities in:

```
    factoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class, Authorities.class, Exercise.class, ExerciseUnit.class, Routine.class, Training.class);
```